# How to get cylinder volume in python 3

Tags: python

I am newbie in programming. I am just following a course on python which is hosted by Udacity. Here, the code prescribed below does not print the function return.

Would you people please help me Thanks in advance!

```
def cylinder_volume (height, radius = 5):
pi = 3.14159
return height * pi * radius ** 2

print (cylinder_volume(10, 5))
```

Comment: You'll want to indent the 2nd and 3rd lines.

Comment: No my friend. I doesn't work indented though
It does not say any syntax error. 
Just show NO output.!

Comment: @KawsarMafruh It will work fine just intend the second and third lines. It will show " IndentationError: expected an indented block " otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @nandukk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few things wrong with your program that I've tidied up (I remember starting to learn python as well). You shouldn't set the variable `radius` to 5 in the function definition, instead input it when calling the function, anyway here's your code tidied up with a few comments that'll hopefully help you out

```
import math

def cylinder_volume (height, radius):
    pi = math.pi    # more accurate representation of Pi using pythons math library
    volume = height * pi * radius ** 2  # Creates a variable with volume value
    print(volume)   # prints out the volume
    return volume   # returns the volume

cylinder_volume(1, 5)   # using this uses only the print statement in the function

print("-----------------")


print(cylinder_volume(1, 5))    # using this prints the print statement in the function as well as the value returned
```

Comment: @KawsarMafruh you've indented the import statement at the top, which it shouldn't be

Comment: Yes!! my friend!  
It works!

very very thanks for your kind help!

Comment: @KawsarMafruh the errors you get in your will tell you what line the error's on and what's wrong, consider using those

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the advice, brother! 
I will remember it.